# Error - can not use root. in the constraints expression - AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I tried to define constraints in the optimization experiments using `root.` ( I did this to access top level agent in the constraints expression field).
I have the variable in the top agent
I tried this with functions, parameters, and variables, and all return the same problem
When I use `root` in requirements there will be no error

However, I got the following error when using root in the constraints expression:
[image: ![enter image description here]

According to [https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/optimization.html#:~:text=A%20constraint%20is%20a%20well,%2C%20e.g.%20parameter1%20%3E%3D%2010](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/optimization.html#:%7E:text=A%20constraint%20is%20a%20well,%2C%20e.g.%20parameter1%20%3E%3D%2010).
I should be able to use root in the constraints expression. See the following in the above link:

> 3 Specify the constraint in the Expression, Type, and Bound cells of the row. In the Expression field the top level agent is available as root.

Then, why is AnyLogic returning this error when `root` is used in the constraints expression?
**Did you face a similar problem? What do you think is the reason?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I think the help is wrong. Constraints are checked BEFORE a model is even created, so access to `root` does not make sense. I think they copied the description from the "Requirements". Those *are* checked after a model is instantiated.

So either use requirements or change your constraints so they do not need access to `root`.

This is confirmed by a quick check on the code boxes. For requirements, you can see the lightbulb:
[image]

But for constraints, there is no lightbulb:
[image]

More [lightbulb info here](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling) :)

Comment: This is what I have done to avoid the root error. However, I'm asking this question because I'm afraid that this (the removal of constraints) will reduce the optimization performance. As you know, the constraints reduce the search space (this is mentioned in the help, too), but they did not mention if the requirement does the same (although they mentioned that requirements help in guiding to the solution): "A requirement can also be a restriction on a response that requires its value to fall within a specified range."

Comment: If I used requirement, what is the effect on the performance?  
If I change my constraints so they do not need access to root., I will need to reduce the number of parameters (decision variables) which I'm trying to avoid as much as possible till I discover that there is no way else.

Comment: Please always open new issues for new questions, SOF does not work like a forum. And if the answer helped, please upvote it so others can find it in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you, your reply answers this question I will ask new questions for the other related issues :)